# cannot figure out making timer in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I haven't added much to my code so far but what it is supposed to do is decrement variable time_1 by 1 every second, it does not do this and instead it turns to 0 almost immediately. What am I doing wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Chess Timer")
root.minsize(250,250)

time_1 = 60.0
time_2 = 60.0

timer_1 = ttk.Label(root, text=time_1)
timer_1.grid(column=1, row=0)
timer_2 = ttk.Label(root, text=time_2)
timer_2.grid(column=2, row=0)

def update():
    timer_1.config(text=time_1)
    timer_2.config(text=time_2)

while time_1 and time_2 > 0:
    time_1 -= 1
    threading.Timer(1.0,update).start()

root.mainloop()
```

I'm new to python, any help is appreciated!

Comment: There are dozens of questions related to timers and clocks on this site. Have you done any research? Also, you definitely don't need the added complexity of threading.

Comment: There are many question about timer and clock, you complicate this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is in the `while` loop. The call to `threading.Timer(1.0, update).start()` does not make the *loop* wait one second; it makes the *calls to `update`* wait one second.. Thus, 60 1-second timers are set almost immediately, and all update the labels at about the same time. The `while` loop, meanwhile, subtracts both `time_1` down to zero in almost an instant, since it's not being hindered by the timer.

For something like this, you don't need to use the `threading` module. You can just use the `root.after()` function to call your function after a set number of milliseconds. Here is what your code would look like using `root.after()`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Chess Timer")
root.minsize(250,250)

time_1 = 60.0
time_2 = 60.0

timer_1 = ttk.Label(root, text=time_1)
timer_1.grid(column=1, row=0)
timer_2 = ttk.Label(root, text=time_2)
timer_2.grid(column=2, row=0)

def update():
    global time_1, timer_1, root

    time_1 -= 1
    timer_1.config(text=time_1)
    
    # Only let the timer continue if it is greater than zero
    if time_1 > 0:
        root.after(1000, update)

update()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think OP wants the count down to stop when `time_1` reaches 0.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for catching that! I fixed the code. :-)